# What is the template to retrieve contents from many tables into single table

Tags: mysql, jsp

How to get data from different tables into one table by searching value(Updatedby) from two tables and to display in a JSP page?

Adding more info:
My table1 name is testraildumptable
My table2 name is timesheet

```
 <tr>
<th style="width: 30$">ID</th>
<th style="width: 30$">Created By</th>
<th style="width: 30$">Estimate time</th>
<th style="width: 30$">Timesheet time</th>
<th style="width: 30%">Updated By</th>
</tr>
<%
try
{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testraildump","roo t","root");
String Query="SELECT id, createdby, estimatetime, executionhours, updatedby from testraildumptable inner join timesheet on testraildumptable.updatedby = timesheet.updatedby where updatedby='"+request.getParameter("search")+"'";


Statement stm=conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs=stm.executeQuery(Query);
while(rs.next())
{
    %>
    <tr>
    <td><%=rs.getString("id")%></td>
    <td><%=rs.getString("createdby")%></td>
    <td><%=rs.getString("estimatetime")%></td>
    <td><%=rs.getString("executionhours")%></td>
    <td><%=rs.getString("updatedby")%></td>
    
    </tr>
    <%
}
}
```

Adding more info:
My table1 name is testraildumptable
My table2 name is timesheet

Comment: Whats `width: 30$`? You mean `width: 30%` right?

Comment: Yes exactly.....

Comment: I am getting "Column 'updatedby' in field list is ambiguous" as error in console. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your error in console:**"Column 'updatedby' in field list is ambiguous"**

Because both table `testraildumptable` and `timesheet` have a column property called `updatedby`,so when query,it do not know which one to choose.

You can update the query sql as below:

```
String Query="SELECT t1.id, t1.createdby, t1.estimatetime, t1.executionhours, t1.updatedby from testraildumptable t1 inner join timesheet t2 on t1.updatedby = t2.updatedby where t1.updatedby='"+request.getParameter("search")+"'";
```